# Using CPUID to get cache size in Ryzen CPU

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-cache, amd-processor, cpuid

I wanted to use the CPUID instruction to get the size for each cache level (L1, L2, L3).

I've been reading ["AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 3: General-Purpose and System Instructions"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjLtb_-itP5AhXNhc4BHe-sBsEQFnoECCAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amd.com%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2FTechDocs%2F24594.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1h4bDkaLjeQ5S6MAC5f1Am). In page 613 there is the information relevant for L1:

[image]

In page 616 there is the information relevant for L2 and L3.

[image]

I have made a simple C+assembly program to print out these values.

```c
const char* amd_L2_L3_associotivity_str(uint32_t code)
{
    switch(code) {
        case 0: return "Disabled";
        case 1: return "1 way (direct mapped)";
        case 2: return "2 way";
        case 4: return "4 way";
        case 6: return "8 way";
        case 8: return "16 way";
        case 10: return "32 way";
        case 11: return "48 way";
        case 12: return "64 way";
        case 13: return "96 way";
        case 14: return "128 way";
        case 15: return "Fully Associative";
        default: assert(0);
    }
    return 0;
}

void cpuid_caches_amd()
{
    uint32_t eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    { // L1
        eax = 0x80000005; // the specific code of the cpuid instruction for L1

        __asm__ (
            "cpuid" // cpuid is the name of the instruction that queries the info we want
            : "+a" (eax)
            , "=b" (ebx)
            , "=c" (ecx)
            , "=d" (edx)
        );

        uint32_t
            dataCache_size = ecx & 0xFF,
            dataCache_associativity = (ecx >> 8) & 0xFF,
            dataCache_linesPerTag = (ecx >> 16) & 0xFF,
            dataCache_lineSize = (ecx >> 24) & 0xFF;

        uint32_t
            instrCache_size = edx & 0xFF,
            instrCache_associativity = (edx >> 8) & 0xFF,
            instrCache_linesPerTag = (edx >> 16) & 0xFF,
            instrCache_lineSize = (edx >> 24) & 0xFF;

        printf(
            "L1 Data Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %d\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            "\n"
            "L1 Instruction Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %d\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            ,
            dataCache_size,
            dataCache_associativity,
            dataCache_linesPerTag,
            dataCache_lineSize,
            instrCache_size,
            instrCache_associativity,
            instrCache_linesPerTag,
            instrCache_lineSize
        );
    }

    { // L2, L3
        eax = 0x80000006; // the specific code of the cpuid instruction for L1

        __asm__ (
            "cpuid" // cpuid is the name of the instruction that queries the info we want
            : "+a" (eax)
            , "=b" (ebx)
            , "=c" (ecx)
            , "=d" (edx)
        );

        uint32_t
            L2_size = ecx & 0xFFFF,
            L2_associativity = (ecx >> 16) & 0xF,
            L2_linesPerTag = (ecx >> 20) & 0xF,
            L2_lineSize = (ecx >> 24) & 0xFF;


        uint32_t
            L3_size = edx & 0x3FFF,
            L3_associativity = (edx >> 16) & 0xF,
            L3_linesPerTag = (edx >> 20) & 0xF,
            L3_lineSize = (edx >> 24) & 0xFF;

        printf(
            "L2 Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %s\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            "\n"
            "L3 Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %s\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            ,
            L2_size,
            amd_L2_L3_associotivity_str(L2_associativity),
            L2_linesPerTag,
            L2_lineSize,
            L3_size * 512,
            amd_L2_L3_associotivity_str(L3_associativity),
            L3_linesPerTag,
            L3_lineSize
        );
    }
}

int main()
{
    cpuid_caches_amd();
}
```

This is the output of the program for my Ryzen 3700X:

```
L1 Data Cache:
        Size: 64 KB
        Associativity: 1
        Lines per Tag: 8
        Line Size: 32 B

L1 Instruction Cache:
        Size: 64 KB
        Associativity: 1
        Lines per Tag: 8
        Line Size: 32 B
L2 Cache:
        Size: 24896 KB
        Associativity: Disabled
        Lines per Tag: 0
        Line Size: 2 B

L3 Cache:
        Size: 2260992 KB
        Associativity: Disabled
        Lines per Tag: 0
        Line Size: 1 B
```

According to this I have 2GB of L3 cache which is not possible. According to the [official specs](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3700x), it should have L1: 512KB, L2: 4MB, L3: 32MB.

Another thing that puzzles me is that `L1DcSize` is only 8 bits wide. That only allows to represent up to 255KB of L1 size, although my CPU should have 512KB L1!

What's wrong with my code? How can I get the actual cache sizes?

EDIT:

Thanks all for the replies. As people pointed out, my bit shifting was inverted. Still there is the question about cache L1. This is what the code looks like now:

```c
void cpuid_caches_amd()
{
    uint32_t eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    { // L1
        eax = 0x80000005; // the specific code of the cpuid instruction for L1

        __asm__ (
            "cpuid" // cpuid is the name of the instruction that queries the info we want
            : "+a" (eax)
            , "=b" (ebx)
            , "=c" (ecx)
            , "=d" (edx)
        );

        uint32_t
            dataCache_size = (ecx >> 24) & 0xFF,
            dataCache_associativity = (ecx >> 16) & 0xFF,
            dataCache_linesPerTag = (ecx >> 8) & 0xFF,
            dataCache_lineSize = ecx & 0xFF;

        uint32_t
            instrCache_size = (edx >> 24) & 0xFF,
            instrCache_associativity = (edx >> 16) & 0xFF,
            instrCache_linesPerTag = (edx >> 8) & 0xFF,
            instrCache_lineSize = edx & 0xFF;

        printf(
            "L1 Data Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %d\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            "\n"
            "L1 Instruction Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %d\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            ,
            dataCache_size,
            dataCache_associativity,
            dataCache_linesPerTag,
            dataCache_lineSize,
            instrCache_size,
            instrCache_associativity,
            instrCache_linesPerTag,
            instrCache_lineSize
        );
    }

    { // L2
        eax = 0x80000006; // the specific code of the cpuid instruction for L1

        __asm__ (
            "cpuid" // cpuid is the name of the instruction that queries the info we want
            : "+a" (eax)
            , "=b" (ebx)
            , "=c" (ecx)
            , "=d" (edx)
        );

        uint32_t
            L2_size = (ecx >> 16) & 0xFFFF,
            L2_associativity = (ecx >> 12) & 0xF,
            L2_linesPerTag = (ecx >> 8) & 0xF,
            L2_lineSize = ecx & 0xFF;


        uint32_t
            L3_size = (edx >> 18) & 0x3FFF,
            L3_associativity = (edx >> 12) & 0xF,
            L3_linesPerTag = (edx >> 8) & 0xF,
            L3_lineSize = (edx >> 0) & 0xFF;

        printf(
            "L2 Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %s\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            "\n"
            "L3 Cache:\n"
            "\tSize: %d KB\n"
            "\tAssociativity: %s\n"
            "\tLines per Tag: %d\n"
            "\tLine Size: %d B\n"
            ,
            L2_size,
            amd_L2_L3_associotivity_str(L2_associativity),
            L2_linesPerTag,
            L2_lineSize,
            L3_size * 512,
            amd_L2_L3_associotivity_str(L3_associativity),
            L3_linesPerTag,
            L3_lineSize
        );
    }
}
```

And the new output:

```
L1 Data Cache:
        Size: 32 KB
        Associativity: 8
        Lines per Tag: 1
        Line Size: 64 B

L1 Instruction Cache:
        Size: 32 KB
        Associativity: 8
        Lines per Tag: 1
        Line Size: 64 B
L2 Cache:
        Size: 512 KB
        Associativity: 8 way
        Lines per Tag: 1
        Line Size: 64 B

L3 Cache:
        Size: 32768 KB
        Associativity: Value for all fields should be determined from Fn8000_001D
        Lines per Tag: 1
        Line Size: 64 B
```

Comment: I've added an answer to your second question to my existing answer. However, in the future, you should stick to one question per question, you have two that are very different in fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you're mistaken in the bit layout of the result. The size results are in the upper bits, but you're extracting the lower bits. The other fields are similarly reversed in order.

For example, `L3Size` is in `31:18`, but you use a mask of `0x3FFF` with no shift, which uses `13:0`.

Instead of:

```
L3_size = edx & 0x3FFF,
L3_associativity = (edx >> 16) & 0xF,
L3_linesPerTag = (edx >> 20) & 0xF,
L3_lineSize = (edx >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Write:

```
L3_size = (edx >> 18) & 0x3FFF,
L3_associativity = (edx >> 12) & 0xF,
L3_linesPerTag = (edx >> 8) & 0xF,
L3_lineSize = (edx >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

And do similarly for the other registers. The lowest bit of a field is the amount by which you have to shift.

---

As for the second question about L1 size, the spec sheet has the chip total. However, what matters from the `CPUID` perspective is that core's cache. If you multiply the 32 kiB of L1i and 32 kiB of L1d by the 8 cores in the processor, you get the expected 512 kiB.

Comment: *what matters from the CPUID perspective is that core's cache* - And also for almost every other purpose for per-core private caches.  Summing private caches across cores is pointless marketing nonsense.  Relevant only in cases where different threads can work on different parts of a larger array or something like that, like cache-blocking within each thread.  Only L3 is shared, and in Zen it's only shared in clusters of 4 or 8 cores (so basically NUMA), so even summing L3 across CCXs is suspect.  Listing L3 as 2x 16MiB would be much more informative.

Comment: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Memory_Hierarchy shows the actual sizes of caches in the OP's Zen 2, confirming that the OP is now getting correct numbers for size and associativity. And shows that L2 is inclusive of L1.  The OP's L3 size is still a sum across [CCXs](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Core_Complex), not 2x 16MiB with 16-way associativity, but I guess that's how CPUID reports it.

Comment: Intel designed CPUID, and normally has one large shared LLC, but Intel has in the past had CPUs like Core2Quad with an LLC not  shared across all cores.  (In that case, it was two Core2Duo dies packaged together, so each just had their usual L2, and communication between them had to go over the frontside bus or something like that.)  IDK if CPUID has a way to report the breakdown of shared LLC into separate chunks for groups of cores.